# What does regex expression doing?

Tags: regex

What does this expression mean?

```
Pattern.compile("^.*(?=.*\\d).*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.COMMENTS)
```

I tried to split each part of the expression, but could not get its meaning. please help me on this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would there ever be a situation where `^.*(?=.*\d).*$` is not the same as `^.*(?=\d).*$`

Answer (score 0):

From [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qV5mV9/1):

[image]

***TL;DR:***

Matches any `String` that contains at least a **number** (characters `'0'` to `'9'`).

---

As a side note I'd like to point out that this is a horrendous way to do so, and could be replaced by the following:

```
Pattern.compile("\\d");
```

I basically removed all the nonsense greedy fillers and the useless anchors. Use this regex with `Matcher#find()` method and not `Matcher#matches()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this regex.
1. The part up to (but not including) the digit.
2. The part from the digit to the end of the string.

The regex is processed left to right.

The first thing it see's is `.*`. This tells it to go directly to the
end of the string and start searching backwards to satisfy ->

The next thing it see's, which is `(?=.*\d)`.
In that assertion the `.*` is ignored because of the previous `.*`
since its already at the end.

So the search progresses (using the assertion) to the left until it finds a
position where a digit is directly in front of the current position.

Once that is found, it matches that digit and all past it until the end of
the string. This is the part 2. described above.

Visually, it can be seen if you add some capture groups, and test it on some
real input.

```
 ^ 
 ( .* )                        # (1)
 (?=
      ( .* )                        # (2)
      ( \d )                        # (3)
 )
 ( .* )                        # (4)
 $
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 15 ) 
12hh34ddd567uuu  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 11 ) 
12hh34ddd56  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 11 , len 0 )  EMPTY 
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 11 , len 1 ) 
7  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 11 , len 4 ) 
7uuu
```